# Getting message for few datatypes as "no default datasource found" for googlefit

Tags: google-fit

can anyone please let me know why I am getting this below message for some of the datatypes i am trying to execute.

https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate

BODY:
{'aggregateBy': [{'dataTypeName': 'com.google.speed.summary',
}],'bucketBySession': {'minDurationMillis': 1},'startTimeMillis':  1600626600000,'endTimeMillis': 1600712999999}

Response:
{
"error": {
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"message": "no default datasource found for: com.google.speed.summary",
"code": 400,
"errors": [
{
"reason": "invalidArgument",
"message": "no default datasource found for: com.google.speed.summary",
"domain": "global"
}
]
}
}

Comment: Also in this "https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources" API i am not getting any source or stream for those segments

Comment: `com.google.speed.summary` is the aggregated data type for `com.google.speed`. You can't aggregate by it, you'd then be getting an aggregate of aggregates. Use `com.google.speed`.

Comment: Hi, I am getting same issue for TYPE_CYCLING_PEDALING_CADENCE and few more...